# crypt() returns null using a salt with a `+`

Tags: centos, passwords, crypt

Why does crypt have a problem with `+` in the salt as of CentOS 8??

**CentOS 7:**

Start by creating a salt on a CentOS 7 machine:

```
[root@localhost map]# /usr/bin/head -c18 /dev/urandom | /usr/bin/openssl base64
M9aZENv5Gm71Y+cwUyaUOcSp
```

Notice the `+` in the salt...

Updated salt calculation: `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9./' | head -c16` -> crypt() charset

```
[root@localhost map]# perl -e 'print crypt("testpwd","\$6\$M9aZENv5Gm71Y+cwUyaUOcSp\$") . "\n `
```

`$6$M9aZENv5Gm71Y+cw$LBRLY1IpcFLA.gNBe0V4nkbP8qg40fhgFv1rIW/U4wTvthNX/nvhEKsXziCxMKSoSOzlv3ukfeIcrXTP26363/`

**CentOS 8:**

```
[root@localhost map]# perl -e 'print crypt("testpwd","\$6\$M9aZENv5Gm71Y+cwUyaUOcSp\$") . "\n"'

[root@localhost map]#
```

So, it's returning `NULL` on CentOS 8. My guess is that `+` is no longer valid in a salt using `crypt()`
It works if you remove the `+` from the salt.  What is going on here and are there other bad salt chars??

**UPDATE**

I found this post https://serverfault.com/questions/88284/how-is-a-password-hash-encoded-in-the-shadow-password-file where it talks about:

If you only want to know how the password is encoded, crypt() uses a special Base64-type of encoding.  Since I was using Base64 instead of crypt() charset, the '+' messed things up because it's not valid in the crypt charset.  Still not sure why it's allowed in CentOS 7 vs. 8..

**Base64 encoding** uses the following charset: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/`

While the **crypt() encoding** uses this charset: `./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

So, I will use this now to create a proper salt for passwords using `tr` to include characters from the `crypt()` charset.

`cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9./' | head -c16`

`ayHTWqcZIT1h.LLg`

Thanks Zak!!

Comment: I learned about salt in college, and since, I've always operated under the assumption that a salt is always `0-9A-Za-z` regardless of OS, language etc etc   --  It was my understanding that's "Standard Operating Procedure" -- College was a long time ago..  So I might be wrong LOL

Comment: This seems to be the case..D'oohh!!  I guess I need something like `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c16` to generate the salt without bad chars.  I wonder why CentOS 7 didn't complain about it?